# Display placeholder in dropdown angular 2

Tags: dropdown, angular2-template

I am trying to display the placeholder of a dropdown if it hasn't any values attached to it. My code:

```
 <md-menu class="mc-dropdown__menu"
  #menu="mdMenu"
  flex="40"
  yPosition="below"
  [overlapTrigger]="false">
  <div *ngIf="options">
    <button md-menu-item
      id="ui-option-{{option}}"
      type="button"
      *ngFor="let option of options"
      (click)="handleOnDropdownSelect(option)">
    <span class="mc-dropdown__label">
      {{option}}
    </span>
    </button>
  </div>
</md-menu>
```

I am not sure exactly how to add the default placeholder. If anyone has an idea please share.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select *ngFor="let option of options (change)="(click)="handleOnDropdownSelect(option)">
    <option selected="selected" style="display:none">Select your option</option>
    <option value="">{{option.yourvalue}}</option>
</select>
```